# Reading file from S3 bucket and writing in current directory using lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

1. Want to read a file from S3 bucket (ex: text.txt) using lambda
2. write file in current directory, to location(ex: __dirname + 'text.txt') using lambda

I am able to read file

```
let txtfilepath = __dirname + 'text.txt'
var params = {   

enter code here
Bucket: bucketname,   
Key: filepathInS3
}; 

S3.getObject(params, function(err, data){   
if (err)
      console.error(err.code, "-", err.message);
      return (err);  
enter code here
fs.writeFile(txtfilepath, data.Body, function(err){
    if(err)
    console.log(err.code, "-", err.message);
    return (err);   
});
});
```

getting error - read-only file system

Answer (score 3):

The only directory you can write to in the Lambda execution environment is `/tmp`, all other folders are read-only.